# Unable to compile Rmd file with external tikz file

Tags: r, pdf, lua, r-markdown, tikz

I'm trying to compile a pdf file from an `Rmd` document with some `tikz` graphics in it.

Example `Rmd`:

````
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: lualatex
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{tikz}
---

# Introduction

Hello.

```{tikz img-plot, echo = FALSE, engine = "tikz", fig.ext = "pdf", fig.cap = "This is my image", code = readLines("testimg.tex")}
```

Figure \@ref(fig:img-plot) is not working.
````

referenced `tikz` file `testimg.tex`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0.5, 0.5) {(a)};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Compiling the `Rmd` file in `R`using

```
$ echo "rmarkdown::render('test.Rmd', output_file='test.pdf')" | R --no-save -q
```

gives me the following log:

> > rmarkdown::render('test.Rmd', output_file='test.pdf')
>
> processing file: test.Rmd
>
> |
>   |
>   |   0%   |
>   |.......................
>   |  33%   ordinary text without R code
>
> |
>   |...............................................
>   |  67% label: img-plot (with options)  List of 5  $ echo   : logi
>   FALSE  $ engine : chr "tikz"  $ fig.ext: chr "pdf"  $ fig.cap: chr
>   "This is my image"  $ code   : language readLines("testimg.tex")
>
> |
>   |......................................................................|
>   100%   ordinary text without R code
>
> output file: test.knit.md
>
> /usr/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS test.utf8.md --to latex --from
>   markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output
>   test.tex --template
>   /usr/lib/R/library/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default-1.17.0.2.tex
>   --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine lualatex --variable graphics=yes --lua-filter /usr/lib/R/library/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/pagebreak.lua --lua-filter /usr/lib/R/library/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/latex-div.lua --variable 'geometry:margin=1in' --variable 'compact-title:yes'  ! error:  (file "test_files/figure-latex/""img-plot-1".pdf) (pdf
>   backend): canno
>
> Error: Failed to compile test.tex. See
>   https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See
>   test.log for more info. Execution halted

The error log shows a double quote in `""img-plot-1".pdf`. Could this have something to do with it?

I used to be able to compile a similar file a few weeks ago, which is why my guess is that some update in an `R` package, `pandoc` or somewhere else on my system broke it. Any ideas what the root of this might be?

System info:

- OS: Linux Kernel 4.19.85-1-MANJARO
- `R` 3.6.1
- `rmarkdown` package: 1.17
- `pandoc` 2.7.3

Comment: You can keep `test.tex` by specifying `keep_tex: TRUE` as an option to `pdf_document:` in the YAML.  Does it show the weird quotes in the filename?  Mine doesn't.

Comment: Deleted irrelevant comment.  Here's what's left:  It works for me on MacOS, with pandoc 2.3.1, so maybe it's a pandoc update.

Comment: In the `tex` file, the file name appears normal. The generated file `test_files/figure-latex/img-plot-1.pdf` is present as well. If I compile the `tex` file with lualatex, it still can't find `img-plot-1.pdf`. Interestingly, it works with pdflatex (not the references in the text, though).

Comment: My `lualatex --version` says `Version 1.07.0 (TeX Live 2018)`.  You might have a newer one?

Comment: Yes, mine says `Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019/Arch Linux)`. Maybe I can figure out how to downgrade it and try again.

Comment: @karpfen Can you add `\listfiles` to the preamble of your .tex file and compile again and show us the .log file? This might be a version issue of your latex packages. Some things recently changed in graphicx

Comment: @samcarter Yes, here's the output: https://pastebin.com/nSXHn37F

Comment: @karpfen Can you try to update your tex distribution? You are using graphics.sty v.1.3c, while the current version is 1.3d.